# Redesign Tableview Cell if its in editing style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableViewController with some dynamic cells in it and a "Edit"-Button. 
The Cell looks like this: http://de.share-your-photo.com/95733637a1

If i press the the "Edit-"button the following code runs:

```
func editCells(_ sender:UIButton!){
    self.isEditing = !self.isEditing
}
```

The red circle (left) and the 3 grey stripes on the right appear. But they mess up my hole cell, it looks like this: http://de.share-your-photo.com/a45ed5ff00

Is there a way to recognize if this cell is on editing style to hide some labels or changing the constraints?

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: is your cell use auto layout ? if yes just make your leading(left) constraint to minus X (x = the padding edit button create) while you're in editing mode.

Comment: but I'm not sure why your "title labels" doesn't effected by that

Comment: if you want you can upload your xib file and i can fix it for you

Comment: @DekelMaman yes I'm using auto layout, this is exactly my question: where can i set the constraint to a minus constant? if i would do this in the cellForRowAt-Method I have to reload my whole tableView if i press the "edit-Button", don't I? Is there no method like i don't now "cellIsInEdtingStyle" or something like this?

Comment: you can done that using the "willTransitionToState" cell's function, and you don't need refresh the tableView you just need to call layoutIfNeeded function from your cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @DekelMaman's comment I was able to resolve my own question. Thanks for that, awesome support! For everyone who is interested in it, here is my solution:

```
class TasksTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var DistanceLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TimeLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var StretchingTimeLable: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var distanceDescriptionLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func willTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
        if(self.frame.width != 320.0) { return } //Continue only if its an iPhone 4, 5

        print("State: \(state)")
        if(state == .init(rawValue: 2147483649)){ //isEditing
            self.distanceDescriptionLeadingConstraint.constant = -22
        } else { //isNormal
            self.distanceDescriptionLeadingConstraint.constant = 16
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are aligning your constraints to UITableviewCell.contentView. In interface builder, you need to check the "Relative to margin" or "Constrain to margin" option.

[image: Make sure you align to margins / contentView of the cell.]

[image: Make sure you align to margins / contentView of the cell.]